# jQuery decision tree, is there a more portable way than this?

Tags: jquery

So I am building a decision tree and it is simply moving from one area to another in aseries of accordions I only have two items that effect the out come but they are used in about 9 different areas.

The first is task (a) and the second is material (b) and the materials can change from one section to the next.

So prj1 > a+b=c

but there can be many tasks within a project, so

a1+b1=c
a2+b2=c

etc.

Right now I am using the task will expand the next accordion which will have a new set of radio buttons, this has to be replicated for each time the task changes the selection. When this changes I have to rewrite my jQuery, and because this is a lot of code, I would like a fresh set of eyes to tell me if there is a batter way of doing this.

My Radio buttons look like this...

```
    <form id="first-metalE">
    <input class="first-metal" type="radio" name="firstE" value="1"> Copper<br>
    <input class="first-metal" type="radio" name="firstE" value="2"> Brass<br>
    <input id="alum-e" type="radio" name="firstE" value="8"> Aluminum<br>
    <input id="stain-e" type="radio" name="firstE" value="4"> Stainless Steel
    </form> 


    <form id="second-metalE">
    <input class="second-metal" type="radio" name="secondE" value="1"> Copper<br>
    <input class="second-metal" type="radio" name="secondE" value="2"> Brass<br>
    <input id="alum-e-two" type="radio" name="secondE" value="8"> Aluminum<br>
    <input id="stain-e-two" type="radio" name="secondE" value="4"> Stainless Steel
    </form>
```

and my jquery looks like this...

```
        function setMetalElectric() {

        // get value from the first radio button group and convert to number
        var firstmtlE = $('input[name=firstE]:checked', '#first-metalE').val()*1;

        // get value from the second radio button group and convert to number
        var secondmtlE = $('input[name=secondE]:checked', '#second-metalE').val()*1;    

        // add results from first and second radio group    
        var mtlselectionE = firstmtlE + secondmtlE;

        // P1
        if ( ( mtlselectionE == 2 ) || ( mtlselectionE == 3 ) || ( mtlselectionE == 4 ) ) {

        alert( ' directs to E1 ' );

        $('#metal-select').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-copperBrass');

        $('.prd-back').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-copperBrass');

        $('.attr-bck-to-mtl').data('toggle', '#electric-mtl');

        // P2
        } else if ( (mtlselectionE ==5) || (mtlselectionE ==6) || (mtlselectionE ==8) ) {

        alert(' directs to E2 ');
        $('#metal-select').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-stainles');

        $('.plum-prd-back').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-stainles');

        $('.attr-bck-to-mtl').data('toggle', '#electric-mtl');

        // P3   
        } else if ( (mtlselectionE ==9) || (mtlselectionE ==10) || (mtlselectionE ==16) ) {

        alert(' directs to E3 ');

        $('#metal-select').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-alum');

        $('.plum-prd-back').data('toggle', '#elec-cat-alum');

        $('.attr-bck-to-mtl').data('toggle', '#electric-mtl');

        // errors   
        } else if ( (mtlselectionE ==12) ) {

        alert(' Error ');

        } else if ((mtlselectionE !=2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,16)) {

        alert(' You didnt select two metals ');

        } else { alert('something is wrong')} ;



        };
```

This is all working I am just thinking that there has to be an easier way of doing this, I am already using a lot of data-target="" and jQuerys .data() but this one has got me wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good opportunity to use a `switch` statement. Maybe something like:

```
switch (expression){
  case "Copper":
    //relevant code
    break;
  case "Brass":
    //relevant code
    break;
  case "Aluminium":
    //relevant code
    break;
  case "Stainless Steel":
    //relevant code
    break;
  default:
    //error handling
};
```

Although you'll still end up with quite a bit of code, this way you won't have to bother with the whole number value system you've created.

Comment: Looks like a decent idea, I will have to look into switch and how to use it and try and apply it to my case. Thank you!

Comment: After I finished this I worked on another decision tree and used the switch, you were right, it worked very nice and I was able to develop something efficient.